# Chart not rendered properly while using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Chart.js[enter link description here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) to draw a Line graph. Problem is with one of the data sets. The max value becomes 8 instead of 128 when I add the third data set with the variable.

```
        datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "#1abc9c",
                        strokeColor : "#1abc9c",
                        pointColor : "#1abc9c",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : response.countStart
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "#3498db",
                        strokeColor : "#3498db",
                        pointColor : "#3498db",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : response.countSeen
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "#e67e22",
                        strokeColor : "#e67e22",
                        pointColor : "#e67e22",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data: response.countClicked
                        //data : [0, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 6, 11, 15, 20, 2]
                    }
                ]
```

I have three datasets and I get them with AJAX and create the chart when i receive the response. Problem occures when I add the last data set to the array. ("response.countClicked") The commented line is that array actually. It is ok when I use it hardcoded but there is a problem when I use that variable. Also it is ok when I use the other variables like response.countSeen or response.countStart at the 3rd data set

Answer (score 0):

I made a work around with options and it rendered as I wanted. I created options and used it while creating the chart and it worked.

```
    // getting the most possible array that contains the max value
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, response.countSeen); 
    var steps = max / 10;
    var options = {
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: steps,
        scaleStepWidth: 10,
        scaleStartValue: 0
    };
```